# Unable to select using angular.element inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have the following HTML for an ngRepeat element:

```
<ol id="animationFrame">
  <li ng-repeat="animationImage in animationImages" ng-repeat-listener>
    <img ng-src="{{animationImage.src}}" id="{{animationImage.id}}">
  </li>
</ol>
```

Within which I want to select based on `id` using `angular.element` like this:

```
angular.element('#animation-image-' + Math.floor($scope.animation.frameImage));
```

Where `$scope.animation.frameImage` is rounded down to be an integer.  I can see that I am using the correct selector (`'#animation-image-1'` is the initially loaded selector, for example) and when I change `$scope.animation.frameImage` using a slider, it works perfectly.

**The problem is** when the page loads, the `angular.element` object returned using a correct selector is `undefined`.  Now, I assumed this was because the `ng-repeat` hasn't populated yet.  So I added the following directive for `ng-repeat-listener` included in the HTML above:

```
.directive('ngRepeatListener', function() {
  return function(scope) {
    if(scope.$last) {
      scope.$emit('NGREPEATCOMPLETE');
    }
  }
```

and I use it thusly:

```
$scope.$on('NGREPEATCOMPLETE', function() {
  console.log(angular.element('#animation-image-1'));
};
```

which is in fact being called at some point (who knows if it is at the right time or not).

Why isn't this working?  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

ngRepeat isn't rendered until the render phase. To access the element via `angular.element()`, you could use $evalAsync:

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function() {  angular.element(...);});
```

$timeout would also work, but it triggers a digest after the $timeout.  If you want access to DOM ready after rendering, and don't want to trigger another digest afterwards, use $evalAsync.

[Edit]

As @maurycy mentioned, $timeout has a second parameter to avoid triggering another digest:

```
$timeout(function() {...}, 0, false);
```

Comment: OK, I tried `$timeout` and `$scope.$evalAsync` inside my `ngCompleteListener` directive and neither worked.  Does that mean this has to be placed in the controller?  Also, would I have to do this every time I call `angular.element`?  If so, this isn't the most elegant solution...

Comment: `$timeout` has a third parameter that's boolean - default true - to call $digest

Comment: @ArtlyticalMedia Agreed not elegant. If you need to manipulate the DOM, I would create a directive.

Comment: @pixelbits you mean to say that I should create my own directive in place of using `<img>` tags?  I guess I still need to think in directives more when using Angular.  I found a work around using a pseudo selector in my CSS but I still think this was a good question to have answered.